# Is cycling a card from your hand considered a spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent has a werewolf transforming card in play, currently with the human side face up.

I have a sliver in my hand with sliver cycling. I cycle this sliver to find another in my deck. The one in my hand therefore goes into my graveyard. I end my turn after revealing my chosen sliver and placing it in my hand.

My opponent wants to transform his werewolf, claiming I cast no spells.

I payed mana, a card left my hand and entered my graveyard. Was that a spell?

Comment: To be strict, you didn't actually "draw" the sliver: it won't trigger any abilities that look for a draw. Unlike most forms of cycling, with *slivercycling* you don't draw a card, you choose a sliver from your library and put it in your hand. I know that's likely what you meant, but MtG terminology is important and I don't want readers to be confused.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, Cycling is an activated ability that you can only use while the card is in your hand. Casting a spell requires that you pay a cards mana cost printed in the upper right of the card.

> 702.27a Cycling is an activated ability that functions only while the card with cycling is in a player’s hand. “Cycling [cost]” means “[Cost], Discard this card: Draw a card.”
>
> 202.1 A card's mana cost is indicated by the mana symbols at the top of the card. ...
>
> 202.1a The mana cost of an object represents what a player must spend from his or her mana pool to cast a card. ...